# word order don't correspond the meaning of a sentence

Tags: meaning, word-order, linking-verbs

> I can't seem to get started today

If we read from the left to the right then we consecutively get following equals:

I can't (to do smth)

where "to do smth" is "seem to get started today"

But "seem to get started today" = "seem as if I get started today". So, we have:

I can't seem as if I get started today

And finally after substitute "I can't"="I am not able to" we have:

(Meaning 1):
I am not able to seem as if I get started today

But It is wrong and the right meaning is:

(Meaning 2):
I seem to not be able to get started today

Why is that?

Comment: You need to explain why you think the plain left-to-right reading is meaning 1. That isn't the case.

Comment: Sorry, I have added information explaining why the plain left-to-right reading is meaning 1 to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't seem to get started today

I agree with all of your logic.

On the face of it, the above means "I am unable to *seem* X".  This implies that I am trying to seem X but for some reason I cannot.

However the meaning that a native speaker will understand is not based on logic but on expected meaning and common usage.

So the intention of the phrase is "It seems that I can't get started today."

You can consider this as an idiom that does not stand up to logical scrutiny. The intended meaning overrides the grammar.